Supersymmetric Wess Zumino term and Fierz identities in $d=10$
When studying the Green-Schwarz formalism of superstring, we came across the following term (the Wess Zumino term) in the action
\begin{align*}
    S_{WZ} = \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha} \int d^2 \sigma [ \epsilon^{ab} \partial_a X^{\mu} \left ( \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^1 - \overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^2 \right ) - \epsilon^{ab} ( \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma^{\mu} \partial_a \theta^1 ) ( \overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^2 )]
\end{align*}
I am trying to show it is invariant under supersymmetric transformation.
So the Lagrangian transform as (up to $\epsilon^2$)
\begin{align*}
    \delta \mathcal{L} = \\
    \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha} \epsilon^{ab} \partial_a \delta X^{\mu} \left ( \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^1 - \overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^2 \right ) + \\
    \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha} \epsilon^{ab} \partial_a X^{\mu} \left ( \delta \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^1 - \delta \overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^2 \right ) + \\
    - \epsilon^{ab} ( \delta \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma^{\mu} \partial_a \theta^1 ) ( \overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^2 ) + \\
    - \epsilon^{ab} ( \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma^{\mu} \partial_a \theta^1 ) ( \delta \overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \partial_b \theta^2 )
\end{align*}
It is possible to reduce this expression (ignoring total derivatives terms) to
\begin{align*}
    2 \pi \alpha \delta \mathcal{L} = 
    \epsilon^{ab}  \left ((\partial_b\overline{\theta}^2  \Gamma_{\mu}  \theta^2 ) ( \overline{\epsilon}^1  \Gamma^{\mu} \partial_a \theta^1 )  + ( \partial_b\overline{\theta}^2 \Gamma_{\mu} \epsilon^2  ) ( \overline{\theta}^1 \Gamma^{\mu} \partial_a \theta^1 ) \right )
\end{align*}
But i don't know how to proceed now! Maybe using some generalized fiers identity for $d=10$?
